# Django display data from mysql to HTML table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a problem when i use Django to display data from mysql to HTML table.
VIEW:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def data_to_list(request):
  data_list = ES_device.objects.all()
  context = {'data_list': data_list}
  #return render(request, 'logfile/data_bi.html', context)
  return render_to_response('logfile/data_bi.html',locals())
```

MODEL:

```
class device(models.Model):
  device_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='aaa', default=None)
  device_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='bbb', default=None)
```

URL:

```
url(r'^data_bi', data_to_list)
```

HTML:

```
<th>..</th>
...
for item in data_list
    <tb>item.device_name</tb>
    <tb>item.device_type</tb>
end for
...
```

but the result just shows the table head, no 's results, why this happen?how to solve this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where does `ES_device` come from?

Comment: oh,my mistake, The MODEL is ES_device

Comment: Then, please update your question!

Comment: Thanks a lot，I lost my rigorous，I use the wrong database，I will close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your template HTML like this:

```
{% for item in data_list%}
    <tb>{{item.device_name}}</tb>
    <tb>{{item.device_type}}</tb>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,guys,I know what happened,I used wrong database to store testdata. It was my carelessness.
Thanks you guys